# How to reference local JS modules in Blazor components?

Tags: javascript, components, blazor, interop

On Dotnetconf two weeks ago I heard it is now possible to include local Javascript files in Blazor components. That sounds very interesting. I guess the approach is still to use JSIniterop and reference the module file.

BUT how do you reference the JS file ??? I have tried all possible creative variants but so far without success.

I am surprised to Google everywhere but find no guides or sample yet on this. All hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can create .js code file next to .razor.cs file and load that file in runtime. It's described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules). Also I found presentation of this feature [here](https://youtu.be/p77UumvZCNM?t=1008) and github repo [here](https://github.com/javiercn/DotNetConfDemos).

Let's say that you have `ComponentA` with `ComponentA.razor`, `ComponentA.razor.cs` and `ComponentA.razor.js` files in `Pages` folder. You can load this module during component's initialization like so:

```
[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

private IJSObjectReference module { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Pages/ComponentA.razor.js");
}
```

But if your component is defined in a component library project then you have to use different file path. For example if your project is named `AppComponents` then this path would be `./_content/AppComponents/ComponentA.razor.js`.

Comment: I followed your sample but still get the same exception. Maybe it is not possible from custom component in other folder than pages?
Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:5000/_content/ProjectName/Components/Common/MyComponent.razor.js

Answer (score 1):

Given a `ComponentLibrary.Blazor` project and a component named `MyComponent.razor` in the `Components` folder. You can include the collocated JavaScript files by creating a JavaScript code behind file `MyComponent.razor.js` and importing the file with the correct path, `./_content/ComponentLibrary.Blazor/Component/MyComponent.razor.js`.

MyComponent.razor

```
<div @ref="_elementReference">Hello world!</div>
```

MyComponent.razor.cs:

```
public partial class MyComponent {
    private IJSObjectReference? _collocatedJs;
    private ElementReference _elementReference;

    [Inject]
    public required IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        _collocatedJs ??= await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            "import",
            "./_content/ComponentLibrary.Blazor/Component/MyComponent.razor.js");
    }

    public async Task InvokeJavaScriptFunction() {
        if (_collocatedJs != null) {
            await _collocatedJs.InvokeVoidAsync("doJavaScriptWork", _elementReference);
        }
    }
}
```

MyComponent.razor.js

```
export function doJavaScriptWork(elementReference) {
    console.log(elementReference);
}
```